# I have created a chat application in which every ten second it takes records from database but i want to show notification at taskbar

Tags: notifications, chat, livechat

I want to show new message notification at taskbar in asp.net MVC or in somewhere to aware user that new message have came.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can show desktop notification by javascript function

function createNotification() {

```
    var options = {
        body: 'This is the body of the notification',
        icon: 'stupidcodes.com.png',
        dir: 'ltr'
    };

    var notification = new Notification("Hi there", options);

    notification.onclick = function () {
        window.open(document.URL);
    };
}

function notifyMe() {
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
    }
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {

        createNotification();

    }
    else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
            if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
                Notification.permission = permission;
            }
            if (permission === 'granted') {

                createNotification();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

first check throgh ajax function if there is any unread funtion then call this notifyMe() function

Answer (score 0):

You can add one Boolean column in you table namely "Seen" with default false value. when user open that message then update that value as true. so you will be easily able get not seen messages for notification. and you can show notification at the top of the page in header section.

Comment: i did same but the requirement is show that notification at taskbar like skpe notification